# Why are there already elements in my ArrayList?

Tags: java

May I know why are there already elements in my arraylist? I found almost similar topics and found the solution is to create the arraylist object within the for loop but I don't wanna blindly follow it without understanding it.

I've tried reading on how Arraylist store memory and it does not make sense to me when I look at my code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HangmanLogic {

    private String word;
    private String guessedLetters;
    private int numberOfFaults;
    private ArrayList<String> letters;

    public HangmanLogic(String word) {
        this.word = word.toUpperCase();
        this.guessedLetters = "";
        this.numberOfFaults = 0;
        this.letters = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public String hiddenWord() {

        for (int i = 0; i < this.word.length(); i++)
        {
            char word = this.word.charAt(i);
            String wordToString = Character.toString(word);
            this.letters.add(wordToString);
            System.out.println(this.letters);
        }
        System.out.println(this.letters);

        return "";
    }
}
```

**Expected results:**

```
[K, I, S, S, A]
```

**Actual results:**

```
[K, I, S, S, A, K, I, S, S, A]
```

Tried experimenting with my code to understand how it works, it seems like it start adding from `[K, I, S, S, A, start, .....]`

Comment: Do you call `hiddenWord()` twice?

Comment: Can you add your code where you are calling that class and its methods? It would really help for us to see the problem outself.

Comment: Please show the code that's calling `hiddenword()`

Comment: How you are instantiating the class? and how you are calling the hiddenWord() method?  Calling  System.out.println two times can print the leteers twice in your case may be length of string times + 1 (outter)

Comment: By the way, `char word` is a poor name for something that isn't a word, especially when that hides the field `String word`.

Comment: You could use a `LinkedHashSet` which keeps the order (like a `List`) but disallows duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are calling `hiddenWord()` method twice. If not use `contains()` method to check if not already their.

```
if( !this.letters.contains(wordToString))(
    this.letters.add(wordToString);
    System.out.println(this.letters);
 }
```